# AFNetworking show upload-progress

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, uiprogressview

I have a question about using AFNetworking and showing a upload-progress.

Scenario:
From a tableview the user can click on a row and go into a detailview. 
In the detailview the user can upload five images. If the user upload one image, a upload-progress view will be visible in top of the detailview.

Pretty simpel. :)

Now to the problem:

Lets say the user retunrs to the tableView, and again go into the deatilview where he just uploaded an image.

Is it possible to show how far the upload-progress is.

/Morten

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#file-upload-with-progress-callback) on the AFNetworking Github page. You should be able to integrate this code into your classes in order to show progress until the file has been uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better link to the example as the githup page does not seem to show how to set the progress up.

https://gist.github.com/andreortiz82/2934606